# Faulty parallelism in phrases [because of + noun // because + gerund]

Tags: parallelism

*Chickens are becoming popular backyard pets, **in part because of the eggs, but also because raising them is fun.***

I wonder if the example sentence above exhibits faulty parallelism, as in the first part of the phrase "in part X but also Y," we have **X= "because of + noun,"** while in the second part we have **Y="because+gerund."**

Comment: Note that "parallelism" isn't actually a rule of English grammar.

Comment: @snailboat No? How so?

Comment: Parallelism is used for a variety of reasons, but "correct" English grammar is not one of them. Parallelism lends a certain balance to expression. Listeners/readers have come to expect it. It can be overdone, but in moderation it can be quite effective. For one thing, it makes some concepts easier to understand and retain. Compare "Seeing something happen will make you believe what you saw," and "Seeing is believing." Which sentence is easier to retain? The first sentence is fine, grammatically; the second sentence is concise, economical, memorable. Moreover, it is a very common expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallelism is not mandatory. It is simply flow and style.

"because raising them is fun" and "because of the eggs" are valid follow-up clauses to connect to "Chickens are becoming popular backyard pets", so it is grammatically correct.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I didn't know it wasn't mandatory.